# Is it possible to change the TabHost/Widget background color? or at least the Application background

Tags: android, background, transparent, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am creating some custom tabs for my Android app, however the designer designed the tabs with small curves at the top. So, between these curves there should be "transparent" color.

Making the curves was not difficult but the problem is that instead of a transparent background color, the tab host apparently has the theme background color (in my case White).

I don't think that it is possible to make a transparent background color as the screen content is above (in my case) of the tabs. The second alternative is to "move" the tabs content some pixels to the top out of the tabWidget but also doesn't seem possible. Last alternative, it would be good to have the application background color to match the default app background color or use a drawable as background.

If any of those things possible?

if not, the worse scenario would be to simply put that background color to each tab; just wondering.

Thanks!

Comment: One snapshot of tabs is worth more than 1000 words.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I hope it helps you.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab);

    host = getTabHost();

        host.addTab(host.newTabSpec(Constants.TAG_TAB1).setIndicator(Constants.TAG_TAB1,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1)).setContent(new Intent(this, Activity1.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec(Constants.TAG_TAB2).setIndicator(Constants.TAG_TAB2,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2)).setContent(new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec(Constants.TAG_TAB3).setIndicator(Constants.TAG_TAB3,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3)).setContent(new Intent(this, Activity3.class)));
    host.addTab(host.newTabSpec(Constants.TAG_TAB4).setIndicator(Constants.TAG_TAB4,getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img4)).setContent(new Intent(this, Activity4.class)));

        host.setCurrentTab(0);


        for(int i=0;i<host.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);
        }
        host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(host.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);// selected

    host.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}


    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) 
    {

        for(int i=0;i<host.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
            host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bg);
    }
        host.getTabWidget().getChildAt(host.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);// selected

    }
```